# Merge two matrices where one may be empty

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

In a loop, I want to merge two matrices `A` and `B` where `B` is sometime empty.

Example:

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2}}; B = {{}};
Join[A, B]
```

gives

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2}, {}}
> ```

but I want

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2}}
> ```

However,

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2}}; B = {{2, 0, 1}};
Join[A, B]
```

should still give

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 2}, {2, 0, 1}}
> ```

How can I obtain `A` as the result in the first case with **{} Curly Braces** without using `If` or any complicated test.

---

I have to mention the level of merge   `Join[A,B,2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
DeleteCases[Join[A, B], {}]
```

or

```
Join[A, B] /. {} -> Nothing
```

The latter requires V10.2 or later.